# How to get a value from DB2 database and assign it to a string value?

Tags: java, database, string, methods, db2

I'm working with my java application connected to a DB2 database. What I want to do is to get a value from the DB2 table that I've queried and assign it to a string value in java, can you please teach me how to? I have tried it myself and I'll show you my code but I think and know that this is wrong, please help...

```
public class GetValueFromDB2 implements ActionListener{
    static String value;

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
      Object source = e.getSource();
      if(source==testValue){ //testValue = a button to test my results
        setValue(getValue());
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, value);
      }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
      //GUI Implementations here...
    }

    public static void setValue(String val){
    try{
      Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:db2://localhost:50000/db","username","password");          
      String sql = "select column1 from \"user\".\"mytable\" where column2='abc'";
      Statement st = con.createStatement();
      ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(sql);
      val = rs.getString(1); //I think this is the part I'm mistaken
      value = val;
    }catch(SQLException e){
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    }
    }

    public static String getValue(){
      return value;
    }
}
```

And the table in my database is like this:

```
"table: mytable, schema: user"
column1            column2
--------           --------
john               abc
jeff               xyz
ian                123
```

So basically, the JOptionPane should display "john" as a string output, that's what I want to do, please help me, I really really need this.

- I'm 100% sure that my database is connected, its just that I can't get the desired value I want because in someway I'm doing a wrong method.

Comment: You've said what the program should do, but not what it actually does.

Comment: can you please elaborate more? my question and the details I've gave could be vague but I believe I gave all the details that is needed... If you're confused with something let me know, please... I really need to at least figure it out at all costs...

Comment: What happens when you run this code? You've said "I know it's wrong". You've said "It should display john". But you' haven't said what it does when you run it. Any exception? What happens?

Comment: ok, I understand now,,, sorry and thank you for clarifying... as you can see, I've set val = rs.getString(1) which in my understanding should get the value of the select statement output. But the problem is, when I run the program an error which says, "Invalid operation to read at current cursor position. ERRORCODE=-4476, SQLSTATE=02501" comes out and there is no string value displayed in my JOptionPane message dialog box. Hope I explained the situation fair enough, I give you my thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You forgot to call `rs.next()` before getting the value:

```
if (rs.next()) {
    val = rs.getString(1);
}
```

If you don't call `rs.next()`, the cursor doesn't point to any row.

Comment: thank you very much @jb-nizet, it worked! I'm REALLY, REALLY grateful to you, thank you very much for correcting such a simple mistake that I made, thank you again!